# XSLT every nth node with a filter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT for some output formatting, and I want a wrapper element around every N nodes of the output. I've read [xslt - adding </tr><tr> every n node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010277/xslt-adding-trtr-every-n-node), but my problem is that the source nodes have to come from a lookup:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)">
```

rather than just a template match. All the examples I've found assume that the nodes you want are all next to each other, and they're just counting siblings.

I have a solution that works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:variable name='num_per_div' select='2' />
  <xsl:variable name='productid' select='1' />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="items-by-product" match="item" use="productid"/>
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <output>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)">
        <xsl:variable name='pos' select='position()' />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1 or not((position()-1) mod $num_per_div)">
          <outer pos="{$pos}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)">
              <xsl:variable name='ipos' select='position()' />
              <xsl:if test="$ipos >= $pos and $ipos &lt; $pos + $num_per_div">
                <inner>
                  <xsl:value-of select="itemid"/>
                </inner>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </outer>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with data

```
<data>
  <item>
    <productid>1</productid>
    <itemid>1</itemid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <productid>1</productid>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <productid>2</productid>
    <itemid>A</itemid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <productid>1</productid>
    <itemid>3</itemid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <productid>2</productid>
    <itemid>B</itemid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <productid>1</productid>
    <itemid>4</itemid>
  </item>
</data>
```

which produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
  <outer pos="1">
    <inner>1</inner>
    <inner>2</inner>
  </outer>
  <outer pos="3">
    <inner>3</inner>
    <inner>4</inner>
  </outer>
</output>
```

But this is looping through all the nodes for each node, which strikes me as inefficient.

Is there a better approach that will produce the same output more efficiently? Can the following-sibling techniques work with a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an outer loop with `position() mod $num_per_div` to get one "iteration" per chunk, then within that select out the members of that chunk out of the whole `key(...)` node set by their position:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)
                       [position() mod $num_per_div = 1]">
  <xsl:variable name="iter" select="position()" />
  <xsl:variable name="first" select="($iter - 1) * $num_per_div + 1" />
  <xsl:variable name="last" select="$iter * $num_per_div" />
  <outer pos="{$first}">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)
                           [position() &gt;= $first and position() &lt;= $last]">
      <inner><xsl:value-of select="itemid"/></inner>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </outer>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The key thing here is to remember that the `position()` function is context-sensitive and means different things at different times.  In the definition of the `$iter` variable, the *current node list* is the nodes selected by the outer for-each, i.e. the list with the first, third, fifth, etc. items returned by the key (so `position()` means the *chunk* number).  But in the predicate on the `select` of the *inner* for-each the current node list is *all* the nodes returned from the `key` function call (so `position()` is the position of the node-under-test within the list of all nodes with the given `productid`).

Comment: Being disconnected from the document turns out to be a real problem for me; I'm actually doing another call-template inside the inner loop and didn't want to have pass in a load of variables (Plus, inside that call-template I'm using even more keys, and I don't want to get into using a key lookup on a variable...). So I'm using this solution, even though it's no more elegant than the one I started with; it's still looping twice in the same way, though I concede that putting the test inside the for-each select is probably more efficient.

Comment: @BenCurthoys it's not looping twice, the outer `for-each` is one iteration per chunk, the inner `for-each` only includes the members of that chunk, so while it still looks like two nested loops, each node in `key('items-by-product', $productid)` is only traversed once in total.

Comment: I don't want to second guess what the XSL parser is doing, but I would expect that

  <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)
                           [position() &gt;= $first and position() &lt;= $last]">

and

  <xsl:for-each select="key('items-by-product', $productid)">
<xsl:if test="position() &gt;= $first and position() &lt;= $last">

are logically identical and probably result is similar execution plans?

Answer (score 2):

You could start by *copying* the nodes of interest into a variable; that would make them - and only them - siblings. However, in XSLT 1.0 such variable would contain a *result-tree-fragment*, which needs to be converted to a *node-set* before it can be processed further:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="items-by-product" match="item" use="productid"/>

<xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="2" />
<xsl:variable name="productid" select="1" />
<xsl:variable name="my-items">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('items-by-product', $productid)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($my-items)/item[position() mod $groupSize = 1]">
            <outer pos="{position()}">
                <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $groupSize]" >
                    <inner>
                        <xsl:value-of select="itemid"/>
                    </inner>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </outer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the sort of approach I was after.

Comment: @BenCurthoys one thing to note is that once you're inside a `for-each` over a `node-set()`, your context node is "disconnected" from the original xml tree. In particular, `/` is now the root of the node set fragment instead of the root of the original XML, so if you need to look outside the fragment for any reason you must put a `<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>` _outside_ the for-each, and use `$root/whatever` inside it.

Comment: @BenCurthoys my approach doesn't have this issue as it uses the original nodes directly rather than copying them into a new fragment.

Comment: I'm not using this solution in this instance because being disconnected is a problem in this context, but copying the results into a note-set is a more interesting technique in general and one which I'm sure I'll use in future. 

No idea which answer I'm supposed to accept.

Comment: @BenCurthoys I thought being "disconnected" from the original tree was the *solution* here - not the *problem*. Without this disconnection, the nodes remain in their original context - which I thought was the *real* problem here. Your question didn't state that the resulting nodes needed to lookup more data from the source tree. I am not at all convinced that the suggested approach has to (or even should) be abandoned in order to satisfy this additional requirement - but you need to provide more details, perhaps ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, it is the solution - because I thought I was looking for a way to make the filtered nodes siblings of each other. But I'd posted a simplified version of the problem to make it clearer, and I didn't realise that using node-set would stop me from being able query the rest of the document inside the "inner" bit. 

The fact is that I have a lot of XSL out there in deployment that doesn't bother wrapping nodes at all, and things break across pages in an ugly way. Where I'm updating an existing transform, I'll probably use Ian's method, where I'm creating from scratch, I'd probably use yours.

Comment: "*If I could mark both answers correct I would!*" That's alright. I believe we are all here because we care about thrashing out the best solutions, not about SO's paper trophies. --- (*But you should have accepted mine, nevertheless, ha, ha, ha...*)