# batch nodes in xslt based on positions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I have a variable in xslt with nodes like:

```
<xsl:variable name='var'>
    <node>1</node>
    <node>2</node>
    <node>3</node>  
    <node>4</node>
</xsl:variable>
```

I want to batch them in some max batch size present in the variable `<xsl:variable name='batchSize' select='2'/>`. Right now what I am doing is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group group-by='position() idiv $batchSize' select="$var">
    <xsl:variable name="batch">
       <xsl:for-each select="."> <!-- hoping to select each element in a group; also tried select="current-group()" instead of select="." -->
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:variable name="batchSet" select="xalan:node-set($batch)"/>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
```

But the above code is not working. What is wrong with this? Please rectify. Open to both xslt 1.0 <strike>and 2.0</strike> solutions.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by  @michael.hor257k that xalan does not supports XSLT 2.0, this explains why current-group() did not work and thus renders my approach completely useless. Please provide a solution that is compatible with xalan. I looked at below link and even then could not resolve my issue:
[grouping based on position](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg00058.html).

**EDIT-2:**
the nodes are generated as:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">
    <xsl:for-each select="row"> <!-- row I am obtaining from somewhere else -->
      <node><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></node>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

**EDIT-3** I can modify the way nodes are created though. You can suggest a change there if possible. Like creating batches at every Nth node maybe?

Comment: I think you want to use `select="$var/node"` at least to have that make sense, I am not sure what you want to do inside of the `for-each-group` as storing the group only to output it doesn't seem to achieve anything. So please show/explain which result you want for that variable you have shown, them I am sure we can fix it.

Comment: Though you say you'll accept XSLT 1.0 solutions, I don't think there are any.  In XSLT 1.0, the value of your variable `$var`, as you've defined it, is a result tree fragment.  Such objects do not support the kind of operation you're trying to apply.

Comment: In particular, then, the first thing to do if you must proceed this way is to ensure that your stylesheet declares that it uses version 2.0 of XSLT.

Comment: @JohnBollinger XSLT 1.0 is Turing-complete.

Comment: @helix If you're using Xalan, then you are not open to XSLT 2.0 solutions. As it is, your attempt is an impossible  mixture of both.

Comment: Fair enough, @michael.hor257k, but "I don't think there are any that you would want to consider, because you would have to implement an XML parser in XSLT" is wordy, and might give the OP the idea that implementing an XML parser in XSLT would be a good idea.  I suppose I should know better than to approximate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can't see why "*you would have to implement an XML parser in XSLT*" to produce the expected result in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I look forward to reading your solution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'll wait for the OP to clarify their processor status. You can post your own question, if you like.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, we are using xalan. If xslt2.0 is not supported then please provide a xslt1.0 solution. I just need to create batches doesn't matter if it is in xslt 1.0. Thanks

Comment: @MartinHonnen I will be passing that variable `batchSet` to another existing template as a parameter. This was not directly related to the question so I skipped.

Comment: @helix Xalan supports XSLT 1.0 only (plus some extensions). Now, can you clarify where are the nodes in your variable coming from? Surely they're not hard-coded into your stylesheet (otherwise you could just as well hard-code them when they are already grouped)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k they are being generated inside a `<xsl:for-each>` loop which is surrounded by the `<xsl:variable name='var'>` tag.

Comment: OK, so why don't you show us an example of the input, so that we can have a **reproducible** example. As asked, your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415867/xslt-every-nth-node-with-a-filter/28416520#28416520 But I believe you're making this more complicated than it needs to be by making your variable a result-tree-fragment instead of processing the original nodes directly.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : I don't have access to that data particularly. I am just modifying and existing code base and this template, it gets applied to somewhere else. So, I just iterate over those rows and create nodes. I looked at the link you provided but am unsure for what those `<xsl:for-each>`  constructs mean. I don't have any `key` defined. I need to group them in batches and order does not matter. But, I guess doing it by `position()` is more feasible so I asked.

Comment: "*I don't have access to that data particularly.*" Sure you do. Run an identity transform on your input to get it as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144082/discussion-between-helix-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can modify the way nodes are created though. You can suggest a change there if possible. Like creating batches at every Nth node maybe?

Comment: I cannot suggest anything without seeing the input.

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you please tell what do you mean by input?

Comment: The XML document that is being transformed by the XSLT processor using the XSLT stylesheet See: https://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/06/03/2b60ff17-0989-11e5-940f-14feb5cc3d2a/diagram1.gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat**: I don't think this is a good solution. But if you're unable to go back and modify the way your variable is created (or eliminate it altogether and work directly on the original `row` nodes), then this should work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="batchSize" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- simulation of generating the variable from the input -->
    <xsl:variable name="var">
        <node>1</node>
        <node>2</node>
        <node>3</node>  
        <node>4</node>
        <node>5</node>  
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($var)/node[position() mod $batchSize = 1]">
            <batch number="{position()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::node[position() &lt; $batchSize]" />
            </batch>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```