# Add class to every third element

Tags: html, xslt

Im using XSLT to build a list of select products.
They are shown in rows of three.
I want to add a class to the right most (third) box in each row to remove the right margin.
Any ideas how I can do this?
Im really new to XSLT.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806578/xsl-for-each-add-code-block-every-n-rows

Comment: all these sequence partitions follow the same pattern as making a table of N columns. Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355952/xslt-rendering-a-node-sequence-as-m-x-n-table . Others: http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+xslt+list+into+table

Comment: ax: care to put that in as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I got from the Umbraco forum. Can't take credit for it, but I'm posting it for future reference.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/child::* [@isDoc]">
 <div class="something">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 0">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">something someotherclass</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  Content of div
 </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```