# XSLT - Produce address labels

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

**UPDATE** Rephrasing the question to clarify confusion.

I am using XSLT and XSL:FO translated by Apache FOP.  I want to print address labels.

**INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<workOrders>
  <workOrder>
    <number>111</number>
    <PartNumber>110022</PartNumber>
    <col3>222</col3>
    <Qty>333</Qty>
  </workOrder>
  <workOrder>
    <number>111</number>
    <PartNumber>110022</PartNumber>
    <col3>222</col3>
    <Qty>333</Qty>
  </workOrder>

  <!--Manually copy/paste the workOrder until you have 47 of them..-->
</workOrders>
```

**OUTPUT**
Page 1 (full page 6 rows x 3 cols)
[image: Page1]

Page 2 is same as page 1.

Page 3 (partial page...in this case 4 rows x 3 columns and last item blank)

[image: Page3]

---

**UPDATE2**
I plugged in Alejandro's solution.  I'm getting an error reported by Apache FOP saying

> xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet

Here's the code translated from the HTML stuff to the XSL:FO. The point of error is marked by comment. What did I screw up?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>

      <!-- layout for the first page -->
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first"
            page-height="11in"
            page-width="8.5in"
            margin-top="1cm"
            margin-bottom="1cm"
            margin-left="1cm"
            margin-right="1cm">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="0cm"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="0cm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>

      <!-- layout for the other pages -->
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest"
            page-height="11in"
            page-width="8.5in"
            margin-top="1cm"
            margin-bottom="1cm"
            margin-left="1cm"
            margin-right="1cm">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="0cm"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="0cm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>

      <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="basicPSM" >
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="first" page-position="first" />
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" page-position="rest" />
          <!-- recommended fallback procedure -->
          <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" />
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      </fo:page-sequence-master>

    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <!-- end: defines page layout -->

    <!-- actual layout -->
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="basicPSM">

      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">


  <xsl:template match="/" name="tables"><!--ERROR REFERS TO HERE-->
    <xsl:param name="pRows" select="3"/>
    <xsl:param name="pColumns" select="3"/>
    <xsl:param name="pSequence" select="*/*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSize" select="$pRows * $pColumns"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pSequence[position() mod $vSize = 1]">
      <xsl:variable name="vPosition" select="position()"/>
      <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="63mm" border-collapse="separate" wrap-option="wrap">
        <fo:table-body wrap-option="wrap">
          <xsl:call-template name="rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                 select="$pSequence[
                                    position() > ($vPosition - 1) * $vSize
                                     and
                                    $vPosition * $vSize + 1 > position()
                                 ]"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:table-body>
      </fo:table>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="rows">
    <xsl:param name="pSequence" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="pRow" select="$pRows"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pRow">
      <xsl:call-template name="rows">
        <xsl:with-param name="pSequence" select="$pSequence"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pRow" select="$pRow - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <fo:table-row wrap-option="wrap">
        <xsl:call-template name="columns">
          <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
               select="$pSequence[
                                    position() > ($pRow - 1) * $pColumns
                                     and
                                    $pRow * $pColumns + 1 > position()
                                 ]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="columns">
    <xsl:param name="pSequence" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="pColumn" select="$pColumns"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pColumn">
      <xsl:call-template name="columns">
        <xsl:with-param name="pSequence" select="$pSequence"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pColumn" select="$pColumn - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <fo:table-cell width="90mm">
        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$pSequence[$pColumn]"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="tables">
      <xsl:with-param name="pSequence" select="workOrders/workOrder[position()!=1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="workOrder">
    <xsl:value-of select="PartNumber"/>
  </xsl:template>

  </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "The difficult part is ensuring that they line up next to each-other in columns." - this requirement is unclear. Does it mean the difficult part is dividing them into rows? Which cells are supposed to line up with which?

Comment: Also are you using XSLT 2 or must you use 1? 2.0 will make this easier.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: There are many answers for these table questions. You need to provide a reduce but meaningful input sample and the exact desired output.

Comment: @Alejandro - there's a simplified example.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: See a very general solution at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480024/xslt-build-multiple-n-html-tables-of-equal-size-in-this-case-3x3/5480453#5480453

Comment: @Alejandro - wow that is a lot more complex that I had envisioned.  I'm gonna give it a shot and I'll get back to you with the results.  At a glance this does look to be what I need...thank you.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: It can be more simple if tables are always composed by 3 columns per 6 rows and the sequence of nodes are all siblings, but it won't be generic then. I'm not going to guess without an input sample.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a partial solution. Let me know to what degree it meets what you need.

Comment: @Alejandro - I tried the solution, but its not working for FO.  I created a simple test case and noted that have xsl:template in a location other than before fo:root seems to be disallowed.  If that is the case I'm back to square 1.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: You have copied the stylesheet inside a an XSL-FO element instead of as top level elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pRows" select="6"/>
    <xsl:param name="pColumns" select="3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pCells" select="$pRows * $pColumns"/>
    <xsl:template match="workOrders">
        <xsl:apply-templates
             select="workOrder[position() mod $pCells = 1]"
             mode="table"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="workOrder" mode="table">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="(.|following-sibling::workOrder
                               [$pCells > position()])
                            [position() mod $pColumns = 1]"
                 mode="row"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="workOrder" mode="row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="(.|following-sibling::workOrder
                               [$pColumns > position()])"
                 mode="cell"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="workOrder" mode="cell">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="PartNumber"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (with 47 `workOrder`s):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>110022</td>
        <td>110022</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 Yes that did it!!!  Yatah!  So, the only other minor detail for future FO implementors is that you need to ensure the `xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"` is defined at the `xsl:stylesheet` level NOT the `fo:root`!

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are no more than 18 orders, you could use something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="Order">
  <tableRow>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[position() &lt;= 6]" />
  </tableRow>
  <xsl:if test="Order[7]">
    <tableRow>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[position() &lt;= 12 and position() > 6]" />
    </tableRow>
    <xsl:if test="Order[13]">
      <tableRow>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Order[position() &lt;= 18 and position() > 12]" />
      </tableRow>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

and then you have a template that matches `"Order"` and outputs a table cell.

Not maximally elegant, but easy.

**Update:**

OK, found out that the above was not what the OP wanted.

Below is a partial solution for the rephrased question. Disclaimers:

1. I do not know FO, so I am leaving that part as pseudocode. Judging by the question title I assume that the part you want help with is just the XSLT.
2. Not being sure whether you're needing answers about the gross structure of the page, or the formatting of each cell, or both, I've addressed the former and not the latter. I'll hold off on spending time on the latter unless I hear from you that that's what you need. Again, not knowing FO, I don't know whether you can format each cell's contents as an embedded table, which would be the simplest way to line up its columns...

Anyway, here is the partial solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="2.0">
   <xsl:variable name="rowsPerPage" select="6"/>
   <xsl:variable name="columns" select="3"/>
   <xsl:variable name="cellsPerPage" select="$rowsPerPage * $columns"/>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="workOrders">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="workOrder"
               group-by="position() idiv $cellsPerPage">
         <!-- <page> is pseudocode for FO markup -->
         <page>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()"
                     group-by="position() idiv $columns">
               <!-- <row> is pseudocode for FO markup -->
               <row>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="cell"/>
               </row>
            </xsl:for-each-group> 
         </page>
      </xsl:for-each-group> 
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="workOrder" mode="cell">
      <!-- <cell> is pseudocode for FO markup -->
      <cell>
         <!-- here goes code for laying out the address label -->
      </cell>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @LarsH: Really? I think is more hard to write this than one of the standard solutions.

Comment: @Alej: probably for you, yes. :-) But I guess I have not mastered the standard techniques as well, as it was easier for me to think this way.

Comment: @Alej - even now I can't think of a more "standard" solution in XSLT 1.0 that is easier than this. I'd be interested to see your solution.

Comment: @LarsH - there are 18 elements per page.  I was trying to simplify the issue, but I think I failed.  I rephrased the question.

Comment: @OP: In that case @Alej is right, a more standard solution would be better. Unfortunately I don't have time to work on that now, but maybe @Alej can answer, or I'll see if I can later on.

Comment: @LarsH - I don't believe Apache FOP has native support for XSLT 2.0.  Otherwise this looks very concise.

Comment: +1 - @LarsH Thanks for all the help.  I'm sure this will be useful to XSLT 2.0 implentations.

Comment: @P.Brian, are you sure that FOP can't be configured to use Saxon 9 or some other XSLT 2.0 processor? Googling for Apache FOP and XSLT 2.0, there are some hits that show potential.

Comment: @LarsH - yes you are right.  It looks do-able.  Since I am on a tight deadline im goin with what works now, but I agree I should upgrade to make life easier soon.